# javascript - get minutes only from iso date time format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am looking for a way to get minutes only from a date in string (coming from toISOString).

When using Date object, I was using getTime(), but dont think there is a direct method available for ISO format.

Would I need to extract strings directly from ISO format, as its just a string?

Code:

```
var depTime = new Date(1222332000).toISOString();
```

This gives me "1970-01-15T03:32:12.000Z", so what is a good way to get minutes which is "32".

Comment: new Date('1222332000').toISOString() is inavlid

Comment: `console.log( depTime.split(":")[1] );` Dirty but works for exactly same scenario.

Comment: The time value provided ('1222332000') is invalid. This will throw a range error: `VM146:45Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value`

Comment: Apologies, mistakenly added single quotes. have removed them.

Comment: Use moment.js and save yourself the headache!

Comment: Yeah, i know, that's real good, but i just had to fix this small issue, so thought will check. I might have to think about using moment now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) from the date object:

```js
var d = new Date('1970-01-15T03:32:12.000Z');
console.log(d.getMinutes());
```

This is the right method, but, if there are issues with the Time Zone, you can parse the string:

```js
var depTime = new Date(1222332000).toISOString();
console.log(depTime.split(":")[1]);  // 32
```

Comment: That's taking into account TimeZone so it returns `2` for me.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Wow? Seriously?

Comment: @PraveenKumar some time zones are 30 minutes off. Probably  `getUTCMinutes()` would be better.

Comment: Should we use methods from Date object. I have been reading some posts and they say that you should never should Date object, as it could create issues for time zones and client time settings. Referring to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Comment: @whyAto8 Yes, I get it... Now I have modified. Check it out.

Comment: @whyAto8 Nopes, in this case, don't use it.

Comment: Right, its working. Thanks. Just curious, should Date object be used at all, if  we have a web app, which takes into account time zones, regional settings etc. Wherever I read, its recommended to use "toISOString()" and if i use that, i would always need to extract minutes, hours, date ,time, like this, would that be right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
deptime.getMinutes(); // 32
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes

Comment: `typeof depTime; // "string"`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just a string, regex should work just fine.

```
T\d+:(\d+)
```